# Turn of month dummy variable

Tags: r, finance, dummy-variable

I have a dataset on a stock exchange's daily closing price and their respective dates for several years. I have further created a counter, counting which trading day in the month each day is (because the dataset is excluding weekends and holidays). It looks like this:

```
df$date <- as.Date(c("2017-03-25","2017-03-26","2017-03-27","2017-03-29","2017-03-30",
                     "2017-03-31","2017-04-03","2017-04-04","2017-04-05","2017-04-06",
                     "2017-04-07","2017-04-08","2017-04-09"))

df$DayofMonth <- c(18,19,20,21,22,23,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

df$price <- (100, 100.53, 101.3 ,100.94, 101.42, 101.40, 101.85, 102, 101.9, 102, 102.31, 102.1, 102.23)
```

I would now like to create a dummyvariable taking the value 1 for the last 3 trading days and the first 5 trading days of the following month, for every month. So it would in this case look something like this:

```
    df$ToM_dummy <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Your `data.frame` is not reproducible as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a dplyr solution. It's probably a little more complex than it needs to be for your real data because your sample stops on the 7th day of a month, and the algorithm needs to know that 7 isn't really the end of the month - the data is just incomplete for that month.

I have therefore arbitrarily added a cutoff of 18 days to indicate that if there are less trading days than that in a month we can assume the data for that month is incomplete. You may wish to change this if needed (I have no idea whether there are always more than 18 trading days in December or February, for example)

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(date)) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(ToM_dummy = +(DayofMonth < 6 | 
                      (DayofMonth > (max(DayofMonth) - 3) &
                      max(DayofMonth) > 18))) # Change to appropriate number
#> # A tibble: 13 x 5
#> # Groups:   month [2]
#>    date       DayofMonth price month ToM_dummy
#>    <date>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <int>
#>  1 2017-03-25         18  100      3         0
#>  2 2017-03-26         19  101.     3         0
#>  3 2017-03-27         20  101.     3         0
#>  4 2017-03-29         21  101.     3         1
#>  5 2017-03-30         22  101.     3         1
#>  6 2017-03-31         23  101.     3         1
#>  7 2017-04-03          1  102.     4         1
#>  8 2017-04-04          2  102      4         1
#>  9 2017-04-05          3  102.     4         1
#> 10 2017-04-06          4  102      4         1
#> 11 2017-04-07          5  102.     4         1
#> 12 2017-04-08          6  102.     4         0
#> 13 2017-04-09          7  102.     4         0
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <-  structure(list(date = structure(c(17250, 17251, 17252, 17254, 
17255, 17256, 17259, 17260, 17261, 17262, 17263, 17264, 17265
), class = "Date"), DayofMonth = c(18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), price = c(100, 100.53, 101.3, 100.94, 101.42, 
101.4, 101.85, 102, 101.9, 102, 102.31, 102.1, 102.23)), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = "data.frame")

df
#>          date DayofMonth  price
#> 1  2017-03-25         18 100.00
#> 2  2017-03-26         19 100.53
#> 3  2017-03-27         20 101.30
#> 4  2017-03-29         21 100.94
#> 5  2017-03-30         22 101.42
#> 6  2017-03-31         23 101.40
#> 7  2017-04-03          1 101.85
#> 8  2017-04-04          2 102.00
#> 9  2017-04-05          3 101.90
#> 10 2017-04-06          4 102.00
#> 11 2017-04-07          5 102.31
#> 12 2017-04-08          6 102.10
#> 13 2017-04-09          7 102.23
```

Comment: Thanks @Allan ! Do you know a way so that I can get `df$ToM_dummy` as a column in  `df` in stead of only in the console? So that when I view df it will return a column showing the dummy variables?

Comment: Edit @Allan : This code seem to not work for the entire dataset. It seems like it does not take into account that the number of trading days each month varies (but is always >18) and so for many of the months none or 1-2 of the last days of the month are given value (1). The 5 first observations are good. I have tried to change the numbers, but I can't figure this out myself..

Comment: @rookie if you drop the number down to 10 does it work?

Comment: no, it works for the first couple of months but then it starts shifting as the numbers of trading days pr month changes. Is there any way the code can be adapted so that it counts number of observations in a month and then assigns the dummyvalues for every month?  So that it takes into account the max of `df$DayofMonth` for every month? @Allan

Comment: Wait, @rookie do you have multiple years? If so, you’ll need to create a Year variable with mutate(Year = lubridate::year(date)) and change the group_by to group_by(Year, month)